# jquery mobile listview data only display when touch on the screen in Android (Samsung Galaxy Note)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've encountered an extreme weird problem on Android device where the data in listview is only displayed while I touch on the screen. I am using `jQM 1.2`, `Phonegap 2.1`, `Eclipse juno 4.2.1` and `Samsung Galaxy Note`. Below is the code:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="sent_receipt" data-title="Sent Receipt" data-dom-cache="true">

        <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a id="a_sent_receipt" href="#search_receipt_option" data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-btn-left" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d" data-direction="reverse"></a>
            <h2>Sent Receipt</h2>
            <a id="refresh" href="#" data-icon="refresh" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d"></a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" data-iscroll>  

            <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_no_record">
            </ul>

            <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_sent_receipt_list_today">
            </ul>

            <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_sent_receipt_list_yesterday">
            </ul>

            <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_sent_receipt_list_this_week">
            </ul>   

            <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_sent_receipt_list_last_week">
            </ul>       

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">      
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->



        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: myApp.getHost() + myApp.getReceiptsUrl(),
            cache: false,
            data: {'email':myApp.getStoreValue('email')},
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: myApp.getRequestTimeout(),
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=UTF-8');
                }   
            }, 
            success: function(res) {

                        if(res.end === undefined) {
                        // some populated data goes here
                            ul.append('<li id="li_show_more" data-icon="false"></li>').listview('refresh').css('display','block');                                  

                        } else {

                            ul.listview('refresh').css('display','block');

                        }



            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {


            },
            complete: function(res) {


            }
```

Comment: this phenomenon doesn't occur in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, just tested on HTC Desire with Android 2.2. The only thing I changed is to remove your `data-iscroll` in your `<div data-role="content">` and added some items to display in one of the listviews, see screenshot

```
  <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_sent_receipt_list_today">
    <li><a href="#itemA">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#itemB">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#itemC">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#itemD">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#itemE">E</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: i tried Dynamic Content and Refresh section in https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview but doesn't work as well. Additionally, I also tried this dude way but didn't work as well. https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview/issues/17